OpenGL® 4.5 Reference Pages に記載されているのはC言語? それともGLSL? もしくは両方？
https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/
上記OpenGL® 4.5 Reference Pages に記載されているのはC言語? それともGLSL? もしくは両方？でしょうか？
下記の引用箇所からリンクされていたので、勝手にGLSLのリファレンスと思っていたのですが、
https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Reference

GLSL standard functions documentation

下記のようにC Specificationという欄が設けられているものがありました。
（C言語の話をしているように思います。）
glActiveShaderProgram

C Specification
void glActiveShaderProgram(   GLuint pipeline,
GLuint program);

一方で、たとえばabsには、C Specificationの欄は見当たりません。absはGLSLの話でしょうか？
注意）
glActiveShaderProgramやabsやへのリンクを張りたかったのですが、JavaScriptでページを動的に切り替えているのか、すべて
https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/index.php
のリンクになてしまうので、左側のサイドメニューからglActiveShaderProgramもしくはabsを選択してご覧ください
GLSLとC言語の見た目が類似しており、パット見でどちらが書かれているのか判別できないのも理由に上げられますが、そもそもこのページの読み方がわかりません（C言語向け？GLSL向け？もしくは両方？）。どのように解釈すればよいのでしょうか？

両方です。最初のページの二段目の文章に次のように書いてあります。

There are two forms of the index which can be selected by clicking at the top of the navigation bar on the left side: a traditional flat index combining the API commands and GLSL functions, and an accordion-style index with separate sections for commands and functions. The flat index also includes per-letter section links.

上記のとおり、デフォルトのflat indexではCのAPIとGLSL関数が混ざて(combining)表示されます。分かれて(separate)表示するにはaccordion-style indexにしてください。「Use alternate (accordion-style) index」をクリックすると、「API Entry Poinst」と「GLSL Functions」にわかれて、どちらであるかが区別できます。
